# HTML input file connection was reset error

Tags: html, file-upload, asp.net-core

We are trying to upload files to blob storage, the process currently works, however, when trying to upload a file greater than ~28.5MB through the HTML input type="file" element, a connection was reset error message appears.  When debugging, the page never hits our httppost method in the C#.  However all files we have tested under 28.5MB will upload correctly.

This is the file input in our cshtml page.

```
<input id="files" type="file" asp-for="UploadFiles" multiple />
```

Our form looks like this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-area="JobManager" asp controller="KnowledgeBase" asp-action="EditItem">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit in Kestrel noted at https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/267.